# React Router Dom : Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I applied all possibility but this console warning not gone.

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.if you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: exact="true" or exact={value.toString()}.

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

I also applied this possibility but not solved my problem:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route exact="true" path="/" component={Home}/>
```

### Full Code:

**Urls.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
...


Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
Axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
Axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";

const Urls = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />  ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                ......

                <Route component={Error} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Urls;
```

**Home.js:**

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import ArticleList from './ArticleList';
import { Authcontext } from '../context_api(redux)/create_context/authcontext';

const Home = () => {

    const { state, } = useContext(Authcontext);

    return (
        <Fragment>

            <Helmet>
                <title>Home Page</title>
            </Helmet>

            {!localStorage.getItem("auth_id") ?
                <div className='text-right m-2'>
                    <NavLink exact className='navbar__btn' to="/register" activeClassName="mylink"> Register</NavLink>
                    <NavLink exact className='navbar__btn' to="/login" activeClassName="mylink">Login</NavLink>
                </div>
                :
                <div className='text-right m-2'>
                    <NavLink exact className='navbar__btn' to="/logout" activeClassName="mylink">Logout</NavLink>
                    <NavLink exact className='navbar__btn' to="/change_password" activeClassName="mylink">Change Password</NavLink>
                    <NavLink exact className='navbar__btn' to="/my_profile" activeClassName="mylink">My Profile</NavLink>
                    <ArticleList />
                </div>
            }

        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Register.js:**

```
const Register = () => {
....
    <div className='register__already'>
      Already have an account? <Link exact to="/login">Login</Link>
    </div>
...
};

export default Register;
```

**Screenshot :**

No any console error

[image]

**but when click on register then below console error occured:**

[image]

Comment: The `exact` prop is a boolean prop, so either include it or omit it, or if you are generating routes dynamically it is either `exact={true}` or `exact={false}`. I doubt the `Route` is triggering this warning though, and this isn't a prop you want to propagate all the way to the DOM, can you include your actual code where the error is coming from? i.e. where is the warning stacktrace pointing to in your code?

Comment: Do you have a `Link` using `exact`? That would cause the error. You might have copied the structure from a `NavLink`, which does use `exact`.

Comment: @DrewReese Extremely sorry for late reply. thank you for your reply..I added some extra code and screenshots please tell me where am i wrong.

Comment: Look in the `Register` component for a `Link` using `exact`, and remove the `exact`.

Comment: Somewhere in your `Register` component it seems you are rendering a `LinkAnchor` component with an `exact="true"` prop on it. Can you update question to include the `Register` component? It likely just needs to be switched to a boolean value (see first comment), i.e. `exact={true}`, or since React props are already treated as truthy/false, just specifying `exact` is sufficient for it being true, and omitting it entirely is false. If we can see the code and logic a solution may become more clear.

Comment: @DrewReese Amazing!!Thank you so much. Error has cleared when I removed `exact` in `Link` in register component.again thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error is coming from here in Register.js

```
const Register = () => {
....
    <div className='register__already'>
      Already have an account? <Link exact to="/login">Login</Link>
    </div>
...
};

export default Register;
```

more specifically, `<Link exact to="/login">Login</Link>` You only use `exact` with the `<NavLink>` component so that you can apply an active class to it if you're currently on that route. If you have this link as just `<Link to "/login">Login</Login>` it should be good :) Looks like you already got the answer in the comments, but figured I'd add it here.

Answer (score 0):

exact it is not to be used in the new version of react-document-dom, It already comes by default because it is best to remove it and the error will disappear.

before.

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
```

now..

```
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
```